# Random number in a range inside an Array

Tags: c, arrays, random

I'm trying to get random a random number between certain ranges in each column in an array so as to mimic a Bingo card.

The first   column should contain numbers from 1 to 10, the second  column  numbers from 11 to 20, the third, 21 to 30 and so on up until the last column,  which contains numbers from 81 to 90.

Here is my revised code based on answers below:

```
 for (row = 0; row<3; row++)
            {
                for (col = 0; col<9; col++)
                {
                    if (col == 0)
                    {
                        bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col * 10;

                    }//end of 1st col

                    else if (col == 1)
                    {
                        bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col * 10;

                    }//end of 2nd col

                    else if (col == 2)
                    {
                        bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col * 10;

                    }//end of 3rd col

                    else if (col == 3)
                    {
                        bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col * 10;

                    }//end of 4th col

                    else if (col == 4)
                    {
                        bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col * 10;

                    }//end of 5th col

                    else if (col == 5)
                    {
                        bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col * 10;

                    }//end of 6th col

                    else if (col == 6)
                    {
                        bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col * 10;

                    }//end of 7th col

                    else if (col == 7)
                    {
                        bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col * 10;

                    }//end of 8th col

                    else if (col == 8)
                    {   
                        bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col * 10;

                    }//end of 9th col

                }// end col for
```

The code now outputs the following :

```
***New Game***
How many players?
1

Player : 1 's card



2       18      25      5       16      26      8       17      22
5       16      26      8       17      22      35      43      54
8       17      22      35      43      54      63      73      82
```

It's still way off once it goes past the 3rd column? From there one value in each column is right?

Comment: What is `rang`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh he probably means range

Comment: 1) Each range is 10 wide, so all should be `% 10` or equivalent, but `col==1` to `col==4` use `11`. /// 2) The ranges are even wonkier for `col>=5`. e.g. `rand() % (60 + 1) + 50` will produce a number in `[50..111]`. /// 3) I think you ran a different version of the code than the one you posted. I don't see how `rand() % ((40 + 1) - 30) + 30` could produce `5` (since you're adding `30` to a non-negative number).

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes range sorry

Answer (score 1):

This is a convoluted means of performing a very simple task

Getting a random number in a range is a simple matter of `(rand() % range_size) + range_start`.

Here

```
for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
{
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        bingoCard[row][col] = rand() % 10 + (col * 10 + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to take into account `RAND_MAX` and that seeding most likely is wanted, by doing for example: `srand(time(NULL));` before calling `rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're really only generating a random number between 0-9 and adding to it the "base" of each column.  Here's a complete example;

```
#include <stddef.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 9
int bingoCard[ROWS][COLS];

main()
{
  int col, row;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (row = 0; row<ROWS; row++)
  {
      for (col = 0; col<COLS; col++)
      {
          bingoCard[row][col] = (rand() % 10) + 1 + col*10;
      }
  }

  for (row = 0; row<ROWS; row++)
  {
      for (col = 0; col<COLS; col++)
      {
          printf("%d\t", bingoCard[row][col]);          
      }
      /* put a newline */
      puts("");      
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code with your suggestion but I'm must be missing something obvious here?

Comment: @ICM89 Here's a more complete example.